# Organize spreadsheet data into a table using python

Tags: python, csv

I want to write code that looks through a spreadsheet and creates a table using specific columns. The column # for the desired values may change in the future, so I would have to search through the spreadsheet using names, not a set number. Here is an example of the spreadsheet given:

```
X,Y,Z,Distance,Speed,Setting
7,38,1,36,66,1
9,8,2,73,51,1
10,11,4,47,77,2
10,8,1,31,91,3
10,11,3,65,72,2
9,9,7,71,83,1
```

Everything is based on the setting, so I would like the setting column to be on the very left. I also need the distance and speed columns, so I do not have to look through X, Y, and Z. I also want the setting value to be sorted in ascending order (the order within the setting itself does not matter as long as all settings at 1 are before all settings at 2 and it goes on). Here is an example of the table I would like to be outputting based on this spreadsheet:

| Setting | Distance | Speed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 36 | 66 |
| 1 | 73 | 51 |
| 1 | 71 | 83 |
| 2 | 47 | 77 |
| 2 | 65 | 72 |
| 3 | 31 | 91 |

I am not very familiar with python so I am unsure of where to start. Let me know if you have any questions, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried, so far?

Comment: @RomainL. I tried using pandas to turn the spreadsheet into a table but I was not able to sort the values and I cannot figure out how to get the columns based on their name, not the column #

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty straightforward using Pandas. Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# read csv file
df_input = pd.read_csv("data.txt", delimiter=",")

# move Settings column as first column
col_set = df_input.pop("Setting")
df_input.insert(loc=0, column="Setting_moved", value=col_set)

print(df_input)

# sort on the new Settings column
df_input = df_input.sort_values("Setting_moved")

print(df_input)
```

Btw you can also just keep the same name `Setting` instead of `Setting_moved`, but just wanted to show that you have to specify a column name.